# D3D11 Best way to decode multiple video in real-time

Tags: c++, qt, directx, directx-11, direct3d

I develop an application in C++/Qt which decode multiple camera IP videos in real-time. Each video stream is displayed at same time in different **QWidget**.

For performance purpose, I use **D3D11** API to perform the decoding, post-processing (color domain conversion and scaling) and rendering.

I'm not sure what is the best architecture to do this. For this moment, I create only one **ID3D11Device**, **ID3D11DeviceContext**, **ID3D11VideoDevice**, **ID3D11VideoContext** and **IDXGIFactory**. For each IP camera stream, I launch a thread to handle the video processing.
I set a **ID3D11Multithread** layer to ensure the thread safety and I create a specific swapchain link to each **QWidget** thank their **winId()**. With this architecture I need to protect the rendering steps because I have some issues with the viewport.

This architecture works fine but I don't if it's more efficient solution. Maybe it's preferable to create multiple **ID3D11Device/Context** etc for each thread to avoid thread safety issue? So, in your opinion, which is the best way to decoding multiple video in real time?